# Deriving mean of percentages from clustered data

Tags: mixed-model, weighted-mean

I am getting into a roadblock about how to analyse this data set. I hope folks here will be able to give me some hints and suggestions.

Here is an example of the data:

[image]

I'm using sugar as the target nutrient. We recorded the three meals of a day, and figured out how many percent of total intake of sugar was contributed by each meal.

I feel that averaging columns C, D, and E can be problematic because each person has different total sugar. So, I suppose weighting the total sugar then computing the mean of columns C through E would be a better approach. It worked out fine, I got the mean percentage with SE and the results made sense.

Then suddenly, I was informed that the respondents could be related. And they provided me with the household id (column B.)

Now, I am a bit confused because I have never face a situation that I need to control for clustering (probably through mixed model using household as random intercept) and weighting.

My questions are:

1. What would be your general advice in deriving the mean of these percentages? I'm afraid I've worked myself into an ivory tower.
2. If there is such a thing as weighted mixed effects model, could you kindly point me to the technical documents? Either R, SPSS, Stata, or SAS is fine.

Comment: What are you trying to determine with this data? What exactly do you want the mean of- what does the "mean of these percentages" mean?

Comment: @ThomasCleberg Thanks! The task was to determine the percentage of sugar contributed by each meal. By "mean of these percentages," I was talking about the mean of column C. I'm interested to know the mean of columns D and E as well...  but for illustration purpose, just column C is good enough. Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting the overall household proportion of sugar contribution by a meal can be done in the following way:

I've added fields `HHpSugarMeal(A,B,C)` that take the household sum of the individual amounts of sugar contributed by a meal:

`(.5 * 10) = 5` for `id` = 1, `MealA`

```
+
```

`(.1 * 20) = 2` for `id` = 2, `MealA`

```
= 7
```

and divides this by the sum of total sugar for the household:

`10` for `id` = 1

```
+
```

`20` for `id` = 2

```
= 30
```

So

$7 / 30$ $\approx$ $.2333$

This gives the proportion of total household sugar contributed by a meal. If you'd rather have the individual's proportion of total household sugar, it's simple to remove the other household members' contribution from the  numerator:

Replacing the the example formula:

```
=$C2*$I2/SUM(IF($B:$B=$B2,$I:$I),0)
```

[image: HHpSugarMealA]

Comment: Thanks! The answer helped me rethink the question and the approach.